# Elasticsearch Function Score changes to 1 on excluded from source field

Tags: elasticsearch, search, scoring

I have an index which has a field x that is being excluded from source, this is the part of the mapping that does it:

```
          '_source' => array(
                 'excludes' => array(
                           '*x'
                      )
                 ),
```

I prepare a query to search through this index, the query has scoring on some fields in the index (including the field x), when i first hit the query, it returns reasonable score on the field x, but after some time, it always returns 1, and I've read that when it always returns 1 then it doesn't read the value from the field.

Comment: May you please define what your question is?

Comment: Why does the score of the field x change from zero to one ? @NikolayVasiliev